# Find Editor inside Active cell (XamDataGrid) infragistics

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, infragistics, xamdatagrid

**How do i find cellvaluepresenter based on ActiveRecord or ActiveCell in infragistics xamdatagrid?**

I tried below code but it is giving null in cell value presenter.

```
    private void grdGrid_RecordActivated(object sender,RecordActivatedEventArgs e)
    {          

  (grdGrid.ActiveRecord as DataRecord).Cells["fldDescription"].IsActive = true;

            Cell selectedCell = grdGrid.ActiveCell;

            CellValuePresenter cvp = CellValuePresenter.FromCell(selectedCell);

            cvp.Editor.StartEditMode();

}
```

this is binding

```
<igDP:UnboundField  Name="fldDescription" Label="Description" BindingPath="TaskItemAction.Description" BindingMode="TwoWay">
                                                            <igDP:Field.Settings>
                                                                <igDP:FieldSettings CellClickAction="EnterEditModeIfAllowed" EditorStyle="{StaticResource textStyleKey}" EditorType="{x:Type editors:XamTextEditor}" EditAsType="{x:Type sys:String}" 
                                                        CellWidth="30" CellHeight="30" AllowEdit="True" Width="0.4*" Height="30" >

                                                                </igDP:FieldSettings>
                                                            </igDP:Field.Settings>
```

So now i want to find Activated record by that event and find editor type and start edit mode.

```
    private void GrdTaskItemAction_RecordActivated(object sender, RecordActivatedEventArgs e)
            {
    grdGrid.ExecuteCommand(DataPresenterCommands.StartEditMode);
}
```

is working fine for me but it is calling edit mode for the cell not the editor(control inside it).

I want to find that editor inside activated cell and make it start editable type.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly get the cell using activerecord.

```
 private void grdGrid_RecordActivated(object sender, Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter.Events.RecordActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        Cell selectedCell = (grdGrid.ActiveRecord as DataRecord).Cells["fldDescription"];

        CellValuePresenter cvp = CellValuePresenter.FromCell(selectedCell);

        cvp.Editor.StartEditMode();
    }
```

Comment: Sorry , i changed my question bcoz suddenly i notice i did't used cellvaluepresenter i have used above mentiod databinding setting\

Answer (score 0):

You could try from getting it from the `RecordActivatedEventArgs` using the the `GetChildCellValuePresenters()` method.

```
var cellValuePresenters = ((DataRecordPresenter)e.Record).GetChildCellValuePresenters()
```

Then you have to filter the array for the `cellValuePresenter` you need.

**Edit:** updated the code to cet the cellValuePresenters, forgot to cast it on DataRecordPresenter. But since you said your problem is different, I will look into it again.

Comment: how do u get this method when i tried to write e.Record.GetChildCellValuePresenters() it's not available in RecordActivatedEventArgs  event

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:***(If you already have the `CellValuePresenter`)***

```
      CellValuePresenter cvp = new CellValuePresenter();

        ValueEditor VE = Infragistics.Windows.Utilities.GetDescendantFromType(cvp, typeof(ValueEditor), true) as ValueEditor;
        if (VE != null)
        {
            VE.IsInEditMode = true;
        }
```

Every `Editor` in `Infragistics` Lib is derived from `ValueEditor`, so use that as a ref to `Editor`.